# Miro: How can I remove points from a spline?

Tags: miro

In [miro](https://miro.com/), I accidentally added too many points to a spline (which has a label). I don't want to delete it (because it has a label). Is there a way that I can remove points from the spline? (Other than undoing straight away)?

I don't seem to be able to select a spline-point and press delete.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find a tag suitable for this - but stackexchagne forced me to add one. This really wants a tag like :drawing: or :miro:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double click or double tap the white spline points to remove them